# CASE alongwith MATCH IN array in Neo4j cql

Tags: javascript, angularjs, neo4j

I am using the following sample code to get all the details based on user data having checked value as 1 or 0.

Here 'WHERE flight.checked IN check' is not correctly matched. Is the usage of 'CASE WHEN user.checked = 1 THEN [1,2] ELSE [1] END AS check' correct along with the match statement?

The result I am getting is user data along with null values as details.

```
MATCH (user:users) 
WITH user, CASE WHEN user.checked = 1 THEN [1,2] ELSE [1] END AS check 
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:HAS_BOOKED]-(flight)-[:OF_TYPE]-(type)-[:HAS_PRICE]-(price:Fares) 
WHERE flight.checked IN check 
RETURN user, type,  price, flight, check
```

Answer (score 0):

If no path matches the `OPTIONAL MATCH`, you'll get null values for everything except `user`. Are you sure that part is correct if you expect paths to be found?

Have you tried running a hard-coded version of the query with values known to match something, like

```
MATCH (user:users {userId: 1}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:HAS_BOOKED]-(flight)-[:OF_TYPE]-(type)-[:HAS_PRICE]-(price:Fares) 
WHERE flight.checked IN [1, 2] 
RETURN user, type,  price, flight
```

to see if it does match?

E.g. does the type of a flight have prices? That seems a bit off.

Comment: The code above is just a sample query based on the original query. Thanks for the reply, I did the check within the result obtained.